# How to select checkboxes by name from a variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am selecting all checkboxes by their name to get the checked boxes like so:

`$("input:checkbox[name=taskResponsesChecked]:checked")`

However, I would like to pass through a variable to `name=`.

For example, `let myVar = "myNameOfCheckbox"`.

I have tried `$("input:checkbox[name=" + myVar + "]:checked")` but it is not working. There are no errors in the console.

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error in console? what is the value of `myVar`? your code is valid, I think the problem is related to the value of `myVar`

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not an error description. What's the value of `myVar`? Show a code sample that reproduces the issue you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give give them a class name and selecting them by class?
Something like:

```
$(".classname:checked")?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox[name='myVar']:checked")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks